# Why is x % 5 == 0 results to numbers not divisible by 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just need to know why the code generated numbers that are not divisible by 5.

```py
for x in range (10,20):
            #if (x == 15): break
            if (x % 5 == 0) : continue
            print(x)
```

Is my understanding correct, that `x % 5 == 0` means all `x` values that have a remainder of `0` when divided by `5`? So would it mean that the code should generate all values that are divisible by `5`?

Comment: `continue` means "_stop the current iteration and start the next one_". when you find a number divisible by 5, you do _not_ print it.

Comment: Your understanding of `x % 5 == 0` is correct, but you should be printing those `x` instead of `continue`-ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `continue` statement skips the rest of the code block and continues the `for` loop with the next item in the iteration. Rather, change `if (x % 5 == 0) :` to `if (x % 5 != 0) :`.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the `x % 5 == 0` is correct. It is `True` is `x` is a multiple of 5 and `False` if not.

`continue` is a keyword used in order to stop the current iteration there and go to the next iteration now.

The code you're looking for looks like that:

```py
for x in range(10, 20):
    if x % 5 == 0:
        print(x)
```

or

```py
for x in range(10, 20):
    if x % 5 != 0:
        continue
    print(x)
```